# Javascript Jquery code just works the first time, next time it doesnt

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in all Javascript stuff and the code is making me crazy.
I'm using Jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="dicesDiv"></div>
```

This div is load at the beginning directly with this code:

```
$("#dicesDiv").load("dices.php?dice1=<?php print ($lastDices[1])?>&dice2=<?php print
($lastDices[2])?>");
```

I have a link to reload this div when clicking it:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0);" onclick = "javascript:rollDice();"><img src="../images
/tirar_dados.png"/></a>
```

This is all my javascript stuff:

```
<script>
......

function rollDice()
{
    <?php $lastDices[1] = rand(1,6);?>
    <?php $lastDices[2] = rand(1,6);?>
   $("#dicesDiv").load("dices.php?dice1=<?php print ($lastDices[1])?>&dice2=<?php print
   ($lastDices[2])?>"); 
}
</script>
```

When I click the first time, it works, but when I click later it doesn't work. It doesn't make sense to me.

Do you know what is happening??

Thanks ^^

Comment: You can't load PHP via JavaScript. PHP executes on the server and JavaScript typically executes in the browser (client). Edit: Nevermind, I guess you're rendering your JS server side? If so, it would be helpful to see the JS only.

Comment: Read the HTML source and you will be enlightened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP code executes *once*, when you first load the page.

Therefore, every click uses the same numbers.
Instead, you should generate the numbers in Javascript by writing

```
1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
```